# Free all arguments in a variadic function

Tags: c, variadic-functions, free

I have a mission to create a function which receives a variable number of arguments and frees all of them, for any type of argument.
I tried to do it using a variadic function, but the thing is I do not know the type of the arguments.

Any suggestions on how to do it?

Comment: Are they all `malloc()`ated pointers? If so: you don't need to know their exact type. If not: you can't "free" them (whatever that would mean).

Comment: free them means dealloc them, they're not all malloc(), some of the might be int,char,BOOL, or any type of arguments, the thing is i don't know how the user allocated them, he might have used malloc(),HeapAlloc() or any other alloc function.

Comment: then it's the second case (i. e. "you can't").

Comment: If you don't know how they were allocated, there isn't a reasonable way to know how to deallocate them.  You are asking for the impossible.

Comment: I smell a serious design problem here. One should not need an awkward hack like this.

Comment: There's an outside chance it might be semi-reasonable if you know how the values were allocated.  If, for example, you have a function that makes six allocations to six separate variables, you might then write a single call `free_everything(6, var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6);` instead of six consecutive `free()` calls to do the clean up (though your variable names would be more meaningful than mine, of course).  But if you don't know how the variables were allocated, it isn't "an awkward hack", it is a catastrophe waiting to happen.

Comment: @user2049815 look at some other questions here at stackoverflow - edit your question in order to make it appropriate (stackoverflow is about coding not giving guides how-to, so explain what did you do, or what have you read about...)

Comment: *"some of them might be `int`, `char`, `BOOL`, or any type of arguments"* - Then those *are no pointers* and there is *no notion of freeing them*. If you actually meant they are `int*`, `char*`, `BOOL*` (note the `*`s), then you indeed don't need to know their type, since a `void*` will handle them equally well.

Answer (score 5):

Treat each pointer as a `void *`; pass that to `free()`:

```
void free_anything(void *arg1, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    void *vp;
    free(arg1);
    va_start(args, arg1);
    while ((vp = va_arg(args, void *)) != 0)
        free(vp);
    va_end(args);
}
```

Example call:

```
free_anything(p1, p2, p3, p4, (void *)0);
```

An alternative design passes in a count of the number of arguments to be freed as the first argument:

```
free_everything(4, p1, p2, p3, p4);
```

The implementation of the alternative function is simple too:

```
void free_anything(size_t n, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, n);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        void *vp = va_arg(args, void *);
        free(vp);
    }
    va_end(args);
}
```

---

Note that the design with a counter (`free_everything()`) is probably better; you can write a function that cleans up multiple allocations in a function that way:

```
void memory_intensive(int size)
{
    int *p1 = malloc(size * sizeof(*p1));
    char *p2 = malloc(size * 32);
    struct wotnot *p3 = malloc(sizeof(*p3));
    struct onemore *p4 = malloc(size * sizeof(*p4));
    struct later *p5 = 0;
    struct muchlater *p6 = 0;

    if (some_condition(p1, p3, size))
    {
        p5 = malloc(size * sizeof(*p5));
        ...
    }
    if (another_condition(p2, p4, size))
    {
        p6 = malloc(size * sizeof(*p6));
        ...
    }

    free_everything(6, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6);
}
```

This frees all the allocated memory in a single function call, regardless of whether `p5` or `p6` were allocated (or if any of the other allocations failed).  However, this is stretching the limits.  However, in such a design, it is crucial not to stop at the first null pointer...just in case there are non-null pointers later in the list.

Comment: If you're referring to the fifth argument of the call, then `NULL` is a valid alternative way of spelling `(void *)0`.  I don't often use NULL, that's all — laziness, or got bitten once so long ago I don't remember what happened, or ...

Comment: I see (yes, I know constant 0 is implicitly treated as `NULL`, it's just that I prefer it).

Comment: You'd have to use `(void*)0` because `NULL` is not guaranteed to be a pointer value, it could equally be just `0` in which case you'd have trouble when `int` and `void*` have different width. For more please see http://gustedt.wordpress.com/2010/11/07/dont-use-null/

Comment: @JensGustedt: It can't be a standard compliant compiler if the value of `NULL` is not a valid pointer.  For example, the specification of `<stddef.h>` says: _The macros are
`NULL`
which expands to an implementation-defined null pointer constant..._ which doesn't leave room for it to be a plain `int` if a plain `int` is not the right size to be a `void *` too.  If you have to worry about that, you may have other problems to worry about too.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, please read the article that I was pointing to. `0` *is* a "null pointer constant" in the sense of the standard.

Comment: I am not sure to understand why the call to free for the first argument arg1 may come *before* using arg1 in the va_start. Should it not be after?

Comment: @DimitriLesnoff — the first argument is a regular argument.  It _could_ be freed after `va_start()`; it _could_ be freed after `va_end()`; there is no _should_ about where it is freed though it _must_ be freed before the function returns (to fulfill the function’s overall contract).  The other arguments can only be accessed via `va_arg()`.

Comment: Thank you! I somehow thought that `va_start` needs the adress contained by the first void pointer to find the other arguments.
It looks like `va_start` is not a function depending on the value, but a macro using the name of the variable `arg1`.

Comment: @DimitriLesnoff — yes, `va_start` is a macro that uses the name of the variable, but that's more or less all.  The macro `va_args` has to be a macro; you can't pass type names to a function like you can with a macro.  The name `va_start` is also required by the C standard to be a macro.  The macros `v_end` and `va_copy` may be functions.  See C11 [§7.16 Variable arguments `<stdarg.h>`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.16) for the details.